# Preview Changes not working when trying to change aggregation format

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to change the Aggregation Format of my notification feed. However, the option "Preview Changes" in the feed editor isn't showing anything. I selected a feed (e.g. notification:2) that has output according to the feed explorer (2 groups with 2 and 5 activities). The feed editor seems to recognize the feed when I search for it (see picture), but it does not show any content, no matter how often I click the refresh button or whatever I change in the format. The manual states "The dashboard allows you to preview changes on your existing data though." so I was really hoping I could do some tests here. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation format is applied once activities are inserted. Thus for changes to show up during the preview you need to add some new activities to the aggregated feeds before opening the preview.

Comment: So the information in the manual about formatting is incorrect? It says that the dashboard preview should work with existing data: "_The aggregation format is applied at write time. Changing the aggregation format only affects activities inserted after the change. The dashboard allows you to preview changes on your existing data though._"

Comment: No it is saying the same thing. "The aggregation format is applied at write time" is referring to the write time of activities to the feed, implying that old activities will not get aggregated by the update aggregation rule.

Comment: True, but it is followed by this sentence: "The dashboard allows you to preview changes on your existing data though."

I assumed it meant that the preview function in the dashboard allowed me to preview changes using my existing data, without having to add additional data (which makes it very hard to make before/after comparisons of changes in formatting). But maybe my understanding of English is not good enough, it's not my native language.

Comment: Yes sorry you are right, I was confused there for a second. But indeed the dashboard preview applies any new aggregation format on your activities that were already stored in the feed. But once you save the aggregation format it is only applied to newly stored activities.